# Reverse a linked list while preserving the original order

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I want to reverse a linked list `head` into a new reversed liked list. I am able to reverse the list but in doing so, original list `head` is also affected and `head.next` becomes `None`.

```
def reverse(head): 
    prev = None
    current = head 
    while(current is not None): 
        next = current.next
        current.next = prev 
        prev = current 
        current = next
```

initially: head :- `1-->2-->3-->4-->None`

After reversal :
           head :- `1-->None`
           prev :- `4-->3-->2-->1-->None`

I basically want head to be `1-->2-->3-->4-->None` .

Here is the code for linked list reversal:-

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

def print_llist(head):
    while (head):
        print(head.data)
        head = head.next

def reverse(head):
    prev = None
    current = head
    while (current is not None):
        next = current.next
        current.next = prev
        prev = current
        current = next
    return prev


llist = Node(1)
second = Node(2)
third = Node(3)
fourth = Node(4)

llist.next = second
second.next = third
third.next = fourth

# print original list
print("Original:")
print_llist(llist)

# print reversed list
print("Reversed")
print_llist(reverse(llist))

# print original list
print("Original:")
print_llist(llist)
```

Output:-

```
Original:
1
2
3
4
Reversed
4
3
2
1
Original:
1
```

Expected output:-

```
Original:
1
2
3
4
Reversed
4
3
2
1
Original:
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your linked list?

Comment: Hi, @MasonCaiby thanks for the response. I have the updated the question with code.

Answer (score 0):

Add `current.next=prev` after the while loop ends. And change your while loop condition to `while(current.next is not None):`

Return `current` from your function and not `prev`. Also, add a condition to see if `head` is `None`.

So your function becomes the following

```
def reverse(head):
     if head is None:
         return head
     prev=None
     current=head
     while(current.next is not None):
             next=current.next
             current.next=prev
             prev=current
             current=next
     current.next = prev
     return current
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just return ```None```? Since the while loop ends when ```current``` is ```None```.

Answer (score 0):

First write `Node` such that you can pass the `data` *and* the `next` in the constructor -

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, data, next = None):
    self.data = data
    self.next = next
```

This allows us to write -

```
mylist = Node(1, Node(2, Node(3, Node(4))))
```

You will see how we use `Node`'s second parameter in `reverse` as well -

```
def reverse(llist):
  def loop (r, node):
    if node is None:
      return r
    else:
      return loop (Node(node.data, r), node.next)
  return loop (None, llist)
```

Notice how we construct a new `Node` instead of modifying `node` using `node.data = ...` or `node.next = ...`. Recursion expresses the solution elegantly and without the need to mutate the original input.

We can convert a linked list to a string using recursion as well -

```
def to_str(node):
  if node is None:
    return "None"
  else:
    return f"{node.data} -> {to_str(node.next)}"

print(to_str(mylist))
# 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> None
```

Let's verify that `reverse` does not mutate the original linked list -

```
mylist = Node(1, Node(2, Node(3, Node(4))))

revlist = reverse(mylist)

print(to_str(mylist))
# 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> None

print(to_str(revlist))
# 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> None

print(to_str(mylist))
# 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> None
```

---

Not really relevant to your question, but you might consider it more "pythonic" to implement `__str__` directly on `Node` so that you can output linked lists using `print` -

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, data, next = None):
    self.data = data
    self.next = next

  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.data} -> {self.next}"
```

Now the user is not expected to use `to_str` or `print_llist` manually -

```
mylist = Node(1, Node(2, Node(3, Node(4))))

print(mylist)
# 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> None

print(reverse(mylist))
# 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> None
```